# Dynamic Programming: Count how many ascending subsets exists in a set

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, math, dynamic-programming

Here is the problem:

> Given an integer *n* and an array *v* of *n* integers, count how many ascending subsets can be formed with these numbers.

There are some restrictions:

> - 1 ≤ n ≤ 300
> - v[i] ≤ 1.000.000, whatever 1 ≤ i ≤ n
> - S ≤ 10^18

For instance, here is an example:

```
Input :
6
5 2 6 1 1 8

Output:
15
```

Explanation: There are 15 ascending subsets.
{5}, {2}, {6}, {1}, {1}, {8}, {5, 6}, {5, 8}, {2, 6}, {2, 8}, {6, 8}, {1, 8}, {1, 8},  {5, 6, 8}, {2, 6, 8}.

I got this problem as homework. I have searched through stack overflow, math stack and so on and I couldn't find any idea.

It would be very helpful if you can give me any **hint** of how to approach this problem.

EDIT:
So I came up with this solution, but apparently it overflows somewhere? Can you help me out

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <queue>

using namespace std;
ifstream fin("nrsubsircresc.in");
ofstream fout("nrsubsircresc.out");

int v[301];
int n;
long long s;

queue <int> Coada;

int main()
{
    fin >> n;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        fin >> v[i]; // reading the array
        s++;
        Coada.push(i);
    }
    while(!Coada.empty()) // if the queue is not empty
    {
        for(int k = Coada.front() + 1; k < n; k++) //
            if( v[k] > v[Coada.front()] )
            {
                s++;
                Coada.push(k);
            }
        Coada.pop();
    }
    fout << s;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This looks like a good start - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/89419/algorithm-wanted-enumerate-all-subsets-of-a-set-in-order-of-increasing-sums

Comment: @djgandy That is a good algorithm but if try to implement it , I find it weird. To do so I would need a 2D array with these dimension [10^17][10^17], worst case scenario. I am sure that it wouldn't work :( ----  EDIT: Never mind, thank you ! Aconcagua solved this issue

Comment: @Vlad-Rares Please do not compare boolean values against true or false, just write `if(<condition>)` or `if(!<condition>)`, i. e. in your case: `while(!Coada.empty())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I implemented greedy approach here:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <array>

using namespace std;
using ll = long long;

const int N = 6;
array<int, N> numbers = { 5, 2, 6, 1, 1, 8 }; // provided data

vector<ll> seqends(N);
int main() {
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        // when we adding new number to subarray so far,
        // we add at least one ascending sequence, which consists of this number
        seqends[i] = 1;
        // next we iterate via all previous numbers and see if number is less than the last one,
        // we add number of sequences which end at this number to number of sequences which end at the last number
        for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
            if (numbers[j] < numbers[i]) seqends[i] += seqends[j];
        }
    }

    // Finally we sum over all possible ends
    ll res = accumulate(seqends.cbegin(), seqends.cend(), (ll)0);
    cout << res;
}
```

The algorithm needs O(N) space and O(N<sup>2</sup>) time.

Answer (score 1):

Let's divide up the sub sets into "generations", where each new generation differs from the next one by the subsets having one value more in length.

Obviously, the first generation is formed by the subsets consisting of only one single number. You get them by simply iterating over the array of numbers.

From each generation, you get the next one by adding to each subset each of the numbers following the last one in the current subset (store this index together with your subset!), but only if the number in question is larger than the last one in the subset. Increment a counter whenever you discover such a new subset.

You are done if you discover the new generation to be empty.

Interestingly, the empty subset is not to be considered???

*Edit:* **WARNING**: Worst case is a sorted sequence of numbers - In this case, the number of subsets in each generation will follow the pattern of the pascal triangle, which calculate as binomial coefficients! So largest generation, 300 elements given, would be `300!/150!` subsets with each of them holding 150 values, which is far beyond what we could hold in memory!

Comment: Will this recover `1,2` from `1,3,2`?

Comment: @Yola With 1, 3, 2, 1G is `{1},{3},{2}`, 2G is `{1,3}, {1,2}`, both subsets created from `{1}` by including 3 and 2 respectively...

Comment: So, you store some data for all possible ascending sequences? Id yes then how many such sequences if array is sorted of length 300?

Comment: @Aconcagua I have made an update with the solution I have built. It works for small numbers , but it crashes for big ones ?

Comment: @Yola No, you only need to keep in memory two generations at the same time - the one you calculated last and the one you are calculating currently...

Comment: @Yola Worst case is a sorted sequence, numbers of subsets in each generation then will follow the pattern of the Pascal's triangle...

Comment: Sorry, is the algorithm the one you proposed? I just couldn't properly understand your post, my English is not good enough probably.

Comment: Ah certainly not, because you have generations of different size sequences. Sorry

Comment: @Vlad-Rares Problem is memory consumptions, see addition to my answer. Have a look at Yola's answer, this one looks correct - and accept it instead of mine...

Answer (score 0):

I will approach this problem by adding up the subsets starting from each of the elements given. This will end up to be a dynamic programming problem because:

Suppose there are 6 elements in the passed `array v {5,2,6,1,1,8}`. Then when we are counting the subsets starting with the `2nd element '2'`, we can use the solutions for the number of ascending subsets starting from the 3rd, 4th or the next elements.

Our definition for the recursive dp function will be:

```
int dp(int index, int lastElementInCurrentSubset){}
```

And answer will be:

```
dp(0,v[0])+dp(1,v[1])+...dp(len,v[len-1]) //returning the number of ascending subsets 
                                            taking nth element in it each time
```

So each call gives the index where to start and for every number ahead than the index, we have an option whether to take it (if it follows the ascending condition) or leave it. We take both the possibilities and return the sum of both.

```
 if(v[index+1]>lastElementInCurrentSubset){ //check array limits for index+1
     ret+=dp(index+1, v[index+1]);
 }
 ret+=dp(index+1, lastElementInCurrentSubset);
 mem[index][lastElementInCurrentSubset]=ret; //can be used when same func params come again which will happen
```

Base condition will be when index reaches the length of the array v. Check whether this is a valid subset and return 0/1 accordingly.